# email loss while using php imap

Tags: php, gmail, imap

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '******@gmail.com';
$password = '******';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "string"');
$mail_ids = array();
if($emails) {
echo count($emails);
}
```

This code gives output of `309`. But, when I search in gmail, using same keyword, I get `344` results.

Any idea where data is lost or where I am wrong?

Comment: gmail's builtin search uses more than just the subject field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'BODY "string" SUBJECT "string"');
```

found more results as per @arnt's comment. Thanks :)